# React form data isn't being sent to express backend

Tags: reactjs, express

I've followed several tutorials and SO posts, but I'm having issues sending data from a React form to the backend. I've tried both `fetch` and `axios` and nothing seems to be working. I've checked the network tab and can see that the request has been sent to the correct URL and it has returned a 200 code - but nothing is being logged in the back end.

App.js

```
// Require modules
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require("express-session");
var cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

// Set up
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
const port = 5000;

// Mongoose
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://georgegilliland:94AJK6OlK5vasVOn@george-cluster-jjfzz.mongodb.net/DPFootball?retryWrites=true&w=majority", {useNewUrlParser: true}, ()=>{
    console.log("DB connected")
});

// Controllers
let login = require('./controllers/login');

app.use('/api/login', function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    res.end();
});

// POST /login
app.post("/api/login", function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body)
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server is on, baby")
})
```

login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './login.css';

class Login extends Component{  

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
        email: "",
        password: ""
        }
    }

    onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }

    handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const { email, password } = this.state;

        const user = {
        email,
        password
        };

        axios
        .post('http://localhost:5000/api/login', user)
        .then(() => console.log('done'))
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });
    };

    render(){
        return (
            <div id="login">
                <div className="background-inner-container">
                    {/* <p>{this.state.response}</p> --> */}
                    <div className="login-register-container padding-top padding-bottom padding-left padding-right">
                        <div className="login-register-title">Account Login</div>
                        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <input className="form-input" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                            <input className="form-input" type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                            <button className="form-button" type="submit">Login</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    } 
}

export default Login
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the Express middleware. An Express middleware takes three parameters: `(req, res, next)`. Currently you are omitting the third parameter `next`, which is needed to forward the request to the following handlers. Also you are currently ending the response with `res.end()` before the POST handler function is reached.

Try this:

```js
app.use('/api/login', function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    next();
});
```

I've removed the `res.end()` and called the `next()` function instead in order to proceed with the request.

**EDIT**
By the way, if you only want to set CORS header, there's a handy and very common Express middleware called `cors`, which is highly customizable and will fit your needs. You can use it like this:

```js
const cors = require('cors')
// ...

app.use(cors())
```

Comment: You have no idea how annoying this has been for me.... I can't believe I neglected this... Thanks man